# Config.groovy in Grails: environments.production.grails.serverURL

Tags: grails

Can anyone give a specific example of when the following setting in Config.groovy is used?

```
// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
    ...
}
```

What I am looking for is a use-case where not changing the above setting will fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is used by some of the built-in Tag Libraries.  For example, the [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html) tag has an absolute attribute that can be set:

> absolute (optional) - If set to "true"
>   will prefix the link target address
>   with the value of the grails.serverURL
>   property from Config, or
>   http://localhost: if no value in
>   Config and not running in production.

Same attribute is used for the [link](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html) and [createLinkTo](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/createLinkTo.html) tags and there might be a few more.

So if you don't change the serverURL in your example, any links you create using the built-in tags specifying absolute=true will probably fail.  For example, the following would resolve to http://www.changeme.com/{context}/book

```
<g:link controller="book" absolute="true">Book Home</g:link>
```